# Get id of post with array in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have one array with the term_id.

```
$termID = array(165,166,158,157);
```

I want get ID of posts that they have **all** elements this array.(Get all posts that they are in the all categories with term_id 165,166,158,157).
Name of my category is newcat.

I wrote :

```
SELECT r.object_id
FROM wp_term_relationships r 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy t ON r.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE t.term_id IN (165,166,158,157)
GROUP BY r.object_id
```

but I get object_id that they have one or more elements of this array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use get_posts instead of manual sql query :

```
$post_ids = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1, // get all posts.
    'tax_query'     => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'category',
            'field'     => 'id',
            'terms'     => array(165,166,158,157),
        ),
    ),
    'fields'        => 'ids', // Only get post IDs
));
```

haven't tried this yet but give it a try :

```
$post_ids = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts'   => -1, // get all posts.
        'relation'  =>    'AND'
        'tax_query'     => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                'field'     => 'id',
                'terms'     => array(165),
            ),
             array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                'field'     => 'id',
                'terms'     => array(166),
            ),
             array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                'field'     => 'id',
                'terms'     => array(158),
            ),
             array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                'field'     => 'id',
                'terms'     => array(157),
            ),
        ),
        'fields'        => 'ids', // Only get post IDs
    ));
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you but the result is the same. I get all posts that they have minimum one of the numbers 165,166,158,157. I want get ID of posts that they have all this categories.

Comment: I've edited the answer, feel free to try and let me know if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for a way to query this to your database? If so:

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE newcat IN(165,166,158,157)
```

*I'm not very expirienced in WP, but you'll catch the drift.*

Comment: The sky is blue. I'm gonna need more info than this... And it's OK to try something yourself.